# Calling jwt-auth secured service from Oracle Service Bus 12c

Tags: rest, oauth, jwt, weblogic12c, osb

Is it possible to invoke it from OSB (!) in more or less "declarative" way, I mean not by requesting a new token for each service invocation? Any approved/recommended techniques for cacheing JWT besides dumb-and-obvious solution like storing it in database and re-requesting on Not Authorized? Or even better utilizing security policies (OWSM functionality) or so. I've "invented" several ways to do it (parsing JWT for validity term, creating cached service with lifetime smaller than that of token) but want to be sure whether they were all not just new bicycles before starting to implement one of them :) Any ideas on non-declarative solutions will also be highly appreciated

Comment: Ok, to clarify my needs better: I have an **authorize** service accepting credentials as a JSON POST request and returning JWT within JSON response. I need to pass JWT value as part of **Authorization** header for calling REST business services. I need to configure some policy but can not get which one and how.